# React, useState validation Function getting the old state value

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nfc

I have this app that scan a NFC tag and create a list of these.

```
import {useState} from "react";

const App = () => {
   const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
   async function scanTag() {
      const ndef = new NDEFReader()
      await ndef.scan()
      ndef.onreading = ({serialNumber} => {
         if(validate(serialNumber)) return alert("already registered")
         let tag = {
            id: serialNumber
            //some other data...
         }
         const list = tags
         list.push(tag)
         setTags(list)
      })
   }
   function validate(id) {
      if(tags.find(tag => tag.id == id)) return true
      return false
   }
   function deleteTag(index) {
      setTags(
         tags.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
      )
   }
   return (
      <div>
         {
            tags.map((tag, index) => {
               return(
                  <div key={tag.id}>
                     <span>{tag.id}</span>
                     <button onClick={()=>{deleteTag(index)}}>Delete</button>
                  </div>
               )
            })
         }
         <button onClick={scanTag}>Scan Tag</button>
      </div>
   )
}
```

The app works fine until I delete a Tag, re-scan the same. The validation function fires and return "already scanned".

console logging the tags array inside the validate function, shows the old array with all the tags still inside the array.
and the deleteTag function delete the tag correctly, I'm not sure why this is happening.
PS: Since I'm using chrome android for debug I can not use ReactDevTools.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue may be due to the `onreading` callback function. This is a closure function which will point to the `tags` value at the time the function is created.

The simplest way around this is to have the closure use an object as the reference to the object will always be the same even if the value changes. For this we can use the `useRef` hook. Also use the `setTags` callback function.

```
const tagsRef = useRef(tags);

// Ensure the tagsRef has the most recent tags state value
useEffect(() => {
   tagsRef.current = tags;
}, [tags]) 

async function scanTag() {
    const ndef = new NDEFReader()
    await ndef.scan()
    ndef.onreading = ({serialNumber} => {
        if(tagsRef.current.find(tag => tag.id == serialNumber)) return alert("already registered")
        let tag = {
            id: serialNumber
            //some other data...
        }

        // Use the setters callback with spread.
        setTags(prev => [...prev, tag]);
    })
}
```